# What is causing text to overlap?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am wondering how come a piece of text which is appended in a table cell overlaps with each other if the text is too big for the cell's width rather than just going onto the next line?

For example I have  piece of text which says `The file upload was successful` but the way it is displaying it is as below:

[image]

Below is the html of the table cell and it's contents:

```
 var $fileVideo = $("<form action='videoupload.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' target='upload_target_video' onsubmit='return videoClickHandler(this);' class='videouploadform' >" + 
    "Video File: <input name='fileVideo' type='file' class='fileVideo' /></label>" +  
    "<input type='submit' name='submitVideoBtn' class='sbtnvideo' value='Upload' /></label>" + 
     "<p class='listVideo' align='left'></p>" +
    "<iframe class='upload_target_video' name='upload_target_video' src='/' style='width:0px;height:0px;border:0px;solid;#fff;'></iframe></form>");
```

Below is jquery where it displays the relevant messages:

```
function stopVideoUpload(success, videoID, videofilename){

      var result = '';
      videocounter++;

      if (success == 1){
         result = '<span class="videomsg'+videocounter+'">The file was uploaded successfully</span>';
            $('.listVideo').eq(window.lastUploadVideoIndex).append('<input type="text" name="vidid" id="'+videoID+'" value="' + videoID + '" />');
            $('.listVideo').eq(window.lastUploadVideoIndex).append('<div>' + htmlEncode(videofilename) + '<button type="button" class="deletefilevideo" data-videoID="'+videoID+'"  data-video_file_name="' + videofilename + '">Remove</button><br/><hr/></div>');
          }


      $(sourceVideoForm).find('.videomsg').html(result);
      $(sourceVideoForm).find('.videomsg').css('visibility','visible'); 
      $(sourceVideoForm).find(".fileVideo").replaceWith("<input type='file' class='fileVideo' name='fileVideo' />");
      $(sourceVideoForm).find('.videof1_upload_form').css('visibility','visible');    


      return true;   
}
```

Below is CSS:

```
    .videof1_upload_process{
    position:relative;
    visibility:hidden;
    text-align:center;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    padding-bottom:0px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    }

.videofileupload{
    text-align:center;
    width:100%;
    margin:0px;
    padding:5px;
    font-size:85%;  
    }

.videouploadform{
    width:100%; 
}

.listVideo{
    text-align:left;
    margin:0;
    padding-left:0; 
}

.videomsg{
    line-height:0px;
} 

#qandatbl{
    border:1px black solid;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    table-layout:fixed;
}       

#qandatbl{
    width:100%;
    margin-left:0;
    float:left;
}

#qandatbl td { 
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#qandatbl th{
    border:1px black solid;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: A jsFiddle might be useful

Comment: Do you have an example page? You could really get a lot of info with firebug. Just select the cells that are overlapping and look for position elements in CSS. Probably the problem has something to do with position:relative;

Comment: Give me 10 mins for the fiddle, @iSenne Do you know what I should change the positioning to because I changed it to absolute but no difference, I like the posistion relative because it places the loading bar in the correct position as it places it in the center of the table cell horizontally, what posistion would you recommend to sort the text out but to keep the loading bar horizontally centered in the table cell?

Comment: @Sienne is better to ask for fiddle so only code relevant to problem exists. You can inspect it just as easily in a console

Comment: Console is coming with no errors, I will have a look but Im sure there were no errors

Comment: using console has nothing to do with errors for this case, use it to inspect the css rules

Comment: I have not quite got the fiddle to do 100% on what the aplication was doing which was overlapping the text but here is jsfiddle which shows css and made up html code: http://jsfiddle.net/TcG9z/14/. I also updated css in question

Comment: @charlietfl Oh ok, well I am using Firebug so I am assuming I go on `CSS` tab, then what do I go on to check css rules?

Comment: look at elements in html tab and will see css rules on right for each element. Can also edit the rules on right to see effect live. Can also click to left of a property in a rule to disable it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with the rule below:

```
.videomsg{
    line-height:0px;
}
```

As you have set the `line-height` to `0px` there is no space between the lines, which is why they overlap one another.

Comment: @Thanks, I thought that would of limited the space of the message between the message and the file input but didn't realise it affected the content as well. Thanks :)